# Troubleshooting Docker Build Failure on Remote VPS with Rust Project: Network Resolution Error

Tags: docker, rust, dockerfile

I created a program in Rust and used `docker init` to initialise Docker. It correctly detected that the project was Rust and let me use a `Dockerfile` made by Docker. I have 2 machines, my local machine: my macbook & a remote machine: vps rented rn from Hetzner to test this (Debian 11). I installed Docker on the remote server using the documentation provided by Docker.
Running `cargo build --release` works on local. Running `docker build .` works on local. Running `cargo build --release` works on remote. Running `docker build .` fails on remote.

The reason why the `cargo build` command succeeds or fails is of importance as the `docker build` command fails exactly on this. I've searched around and asked my friends. One of my friends said it might be a network interface configuration error. But I still have no clue!

As I said before, the dockerfile was generated by Docker, but for reference:

```
ARG RUST_VERSION=1.74.1
ARG APP_NAME=redis-rest
FROM rust:${RUST_VERSION}-slim-bullseye AS build
ARG APP_NAME
WORKDIR /app
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=src,target=src \
    --mount=type=bind,source=Cargo.toml,target=Cargo.toml \
    --mount=type=bind,source=Cargo.lock,target=Cargo.lock \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/app/target/ \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/usr/local/cargo/registry/ \
    <<EOF
set -e
cargo build --locked --release
cp ./target/release/$APP_NAME /bin/server
EOF
FROM debian:bullseye-slim AS final
ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser
USER appuser
COPY --from=build /bin/server /bin/
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["/bin/server"]
```

And the error:

```
0.180     Updating crates.io index                                              
0.182 warning: spurious network error (3 tries remaining): [6] Couldn't resolve host name (Could not resolve host: index.crates.io)
1.570 warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): [6] Couldn't resolve host name (Could not resolve host: index.crates.io)
5.070 warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): [6] Couldn't resolve host name (Could not resolve host: index.crates.io)
11.57 error: failed to get `dotenv` as a dependency of package `redis-rest v0.1.0 (/app)`
11.57 
11.57 Caused by:
11.57   failed to query replaced source registry `crates-io`
11.57 
11.57 Caused by:
11.57   download of config.json failed
11.57 
11.57 Caused by:
11.57   failed to download from `https://index.crates.io/config.json`
11.57 
11.57 Caused by:
11.57   [6] Couldn't resolve host name (Could not resolve host: index.crates.io)
```

As you can see, it can't resolve the host name for the package management within Rust. But pinging / curling / anything else works to that same host name.
Could anyone help me with this // steer me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the solution to this with some friends! Apparently IPv6 isn't enabled on default by Docker, and the server I was running only had an IPv6 ip!

By following the guide written by Docker: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/ it was easily fixed!